# Randomization of Groups

Tags: java, random

I'm having a problem finding a way to completely randomize the people being added to these 4 different groups. It works right now but it isn't fully randomized. Any help would be appreciated.

I've only shuffled it which doesn't solve the issue that it isn't completely random.

```
public class RandomGroup
{
   /**
    * Arraylist of subgroups in an arraylist of groups 
    * Instance variables fr and sc for file reader and scanner
    */
    private ArrayList<String> subgroup;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> group;
    public FileReader fr;
    public Scanner sc;


    /**
     * @param subgroup
     * @param group
     */
    public RandomGroup()
    {
    this.subgroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.group = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    }

    /**
     * Creates a method readAndSopFile uses the scanner class to go through 
     * the file
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     * @throws NoSuchElementException
     */
    public void readAndSopFile() throws IllegalStateException, NoSuchElementException
    {
    while (sc.hasNext())
    {
        String s = sc.next();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    }
    /**
     * Creates the method groupAndSubgroup
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     * @throws NoSuchElementException
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * Creates a fileReader and a scanner to read the file "Students"
     */
    public void groupAndSubgroup() throws IllegalStateException,    NoSuchElementException, FileNotFoundException
    {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Students.txt");
    //fr = new FileReader("Students.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
    /**
     * Creates another array group from subgroup and adds elements from the
     * text file to the subgroup.
     * Then adds the subgroup to group 0.
     */
    this.subgroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    group.add(0, subgroup);

    /**
     * Creates another array group from subgroup and adds elements from the
     * text file to the subgroup.
     * Then adds the subgroup to group 1.
     */
    this.subgroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    group.add(1, subgroup);

    /**
     * Creates another array group from subgroup and adds elements from the
     * text file to the subgroup.
     * Then adds the subgroup to group 2.
     */
    this.subgroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    group.add(2, subgroup);

    /**
     * Creates another array group from subgroup and adds elements from the
     * text file to the subgroup.
     * Then adds the subgroup to group 3.
     */
    this.subgroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    subgroup.add(sc.next());
    group.add(3, subgroup);
    /**
     * Executes the method SOP
     */
    this.SOP();
    /**
     * Closes the scanner
     */
    sc.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method shuffles the group array list and outputs the group numbers
     * with the group names till all are in groups.
     */
    public void SOP()
    {

       Collections.shuffle(group);
       for (int i = 0; i < group.size(); i++)
       {
        System.out.println("Group #" + (i+1));
        for (int j = 0; j < group.get(i).size(); j++)
        {
            System.out.println(group.get(i).get(j));
        }
        System.out.println();
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    /**
     * Executes the method groupAndSubgroup
     */
    RandomGroup rg = new RandomGroup();
    rg.groupAndSubgroup();
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: This isn't very clear.  You've given us a wall of code, and a vague description of something you'd like to achieve.  Please be more specific...

Comment: What do you mean by it isn't completely random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what do you want to do, you can try this:

```
List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();

Collections.shuffle(groups);
```

Where, `Collection` is a java class..

This is [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29), an extract is :

> public static void shuffle(List list)
>
> Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of
>   randomness. **All permutations occur with approximately equal
>   likelihood.**